# Send image via Guzzle Client

Tags: php, guzzle

How to send POST request with an image via Guzzle(PHP)?

Via curl, everything should be something like this:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://example.com.ua/api/add" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "files=@image.png;type=image/png" -F "test=test"
```

I tried:

```
$multipart = [
    [
        'name'     => 'test',
        'contents' => 'test'
    ], [
        'name'     => 'files',
        'contents' => fopen(public_path($this->user->imagePath()), 'r'),
        'filename' => 'filename' . '.' . File::extension(public_path($this->user->imagePath())),
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']
        ],
    ];

$guzzleClient->request(
    'POST',
    self::BASE_URL . '/add',
    array_merge([RequestOptions::MULTIPART => $multipart], ['headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ]])
);
```

Everything by

```
 <a href="http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart">docs</a>
```

External API tell me after debug - `field "files" missed Content-Type: image/jpeg`

What am I doing wrong?

How to execute this query in Guzzle?

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: at least you have an error in this expression `array_merge([RequestOptions::MULTIPART => $multipart], ['headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ]])`

Comment: result of this expression is `[RequestOptions::MULTIPART => $multipart, 'headers' => [ 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data' ]]`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ ArtemIIchenko Nope, array_mergre work fine.
External API tell me after debug, field "files" missed Content-Type: image/jpeg